# Data Extension with Logos

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am trying to finalize an email and have run into an issue. The email needs to be dynamic in terms of the logo, as it should swap out based on the company that the audience member is associated with. For example, if the person is an Apple customer, the Apple logo should appear and vice versa for Boost Mobile customers.

I have a data extension that houses the list of retailers along with their logo image. Is there a way to lookup the row of the data extension of retailers based and then call the logo to appear dynamically based on the company associated with the contact?

I am unsure if this is possible but here is what I have so far:
Data extension name is "retailers"

```
SET @storeId = [storeId] //storeId is from the customer's profile 
SET @Retailer = LookupRows('retailers','logo', @storeId)
```

then in the html, I have
`%%=v(@Retailer)=%%`

Thank you in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SFSE! You can handle this with Basic Lookup something like below:

```
%%[
set @storeID = AttributeValue("StoreID") 
set @Retailer = Lookup("Retailers","Logo","StoreID", @storeID)
]%%

Retailer: %%=v(@Retailer)=%%
```

More context: https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Assuming you're storing the logos' URLs in your DE so you will need to use "RedirectTo" instead of "V"

```
 Retailer: %%=RedirectTo(@Retailer)=%%
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!